# An easy way to switch from Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache2, migration, nginx

I use nginx as DAV server and apache which hosts a frontend to backuppc.
I'd like to make nginx host the frontend insead of apache. But I don't have a clue how to translate apache settings to nginx ones. Can you help me with it? Is there a guide how to translate /etc/apache2/apache2.conf into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Despite apache2.conf is rather big, I found the only section related to the frontend.

> 

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
Alias /backuppc /usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/

<Directory /usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/>
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all

        # Uncomment the line below to ensure that nobody can sniff importanti
        # info from network traffic during editing of the BackupPC config or
        # when browsing/restoring backups.
        # Requires that you have your webserver set up for SSL (https) access.
        #SSLRequireSSL

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi

    AuthGroupFile /etc/backuppc/htgroup
        AuthUserFile /etc/backuppc/htpasswd
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "BackupPC admin"
    require valid-user

</Directory>
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Pretty much just have to learn nginx. Different than Apache configs but still just as easy... http://www.nginx.com/docs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is ready to use config [here](https://github.com/Zloy/backuppc_on_nginx).